# get slice returning inconsistent results

Tags: cassandra, thrift, slice

I'm using a wide column index to order records in a timeline fashion, a la:

```
"TimelineIndex" //CF name
  [CFName] //row key
    [TimeUUID]:[CFRowKey] //column name/value
    [TimeUUID]:[CFRowKey] //column name/value
    [TimeUUID]:[CFRowKey] //column name/value
    [TimeUUID]:[CFRowKey] //column name/value
```

Assume I have 10 records in the TimelineIndex CF with one column per day, ranging from '01/01/2013 12:00:00' to '10/01/2013 12:00:00' (as TimeUUIDs), and I run the following get_slice() command:

```
var predicate = new SlicePredicate(){ Slice_range = new SliceRange() {
{
  Start = TimeGenerator.GetTimeUUID(new DateTime("06/01/2013 12:00:00"),
  Finish = TimeGenerator.GetTimeUUID(new DateTime("11/01/2013 12:00:00"),
  Count = 5,
  Reversed = false
}};
var results = client.get_slice([CFName], parent, predicate, consitencylevel.one);
```

The columns returned by this query aren't always consistent. The majority of the time the column named '06/01/2013 12:00:00' is returned, but every so often (about 1 in 10 executions) that column is excluded from the results and I end up with only 4 columns returned.

I cant for the life of me figure out why I would be getting inconsistent results here. Can any suggest a reason for this?

And before anyone says, I know its not advisable to use Thrift directly - this is purely a proof of concept exercise!

Comment: How many nodes are in your cluster, and what is your replication factor?

Comment: 3 nodes in cluster. Replication factor of 2. I wouldnt have thought that would matter though, as I'm requesting data from a single row, which is supposed to be contained in its entirety on one node.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the risk of belaboring the obvious, remember that TimeUUIDs (version 1 UUIDs) serve two purposes:

- They have a time-based component
- They are UUIDs

Thus, you can insert multiple time-based data values and get them back chronologically without worrying about losing data due to column name collisions.

Also remember that column names must be globally ordered for Cassandra to find your data correctly, and UUIDs are no exception.  Thus, if you give Cassandra two TimeUUIDs with the same time component, it will order them based on the non-time-components.

So, what's happening is a subtle interaction of the above two points: when you create new random-ish TimeUUIDs at `06/01/2013 12:00:00`, sometimes that sorts before the one you inserted, and sometimes it does not.  When it does not, then the first column won't be included.

To fix this you'd need to deliberately construct non-time components for the query UUID to sort as low as possible.  The pycassa library does this, for instance.

Comment: Interesting. That would explain it to a point. However, the data remains constant when I run these queries (i.e. Im not re-inserting the data each time) yet the results returned varies as described. Surely cassandra isnt repeatedly re-sorting the columns without new data being inserted?

Comment: So finally I can confirm that you were spot on Jonathan. The variable part of the TimeUUID was causing the variable results. Thanks all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your issue may be related to your consistency level.  You have 2 replicas, yet you are reading with consistency level of ONE.  If you also write with ONE, you will run into issues as you describe.  If you change your read level to QUORUM (or LOCAL_QUORUM), my guess is your data will never disappear.  Sporadically disappearing data is almost always a consistency issue.

Why does this happen?

Using your setup of 3 nodes with RF=2, let's say you write column A with CL=ONE.  Now you have one node (let's say N1) with column A, and the other node that would theoretically get the replica (let's say N2) does not yet have it.  So you'll end up with this:

```
N1: has A
N2: does not have A
N3: will look to N1 or N2 for A
```

So now, let's see what would happen if, using CL=ONE, you ask each node for A:

```
N1: you get A
N2: you get nothing because it doesn't check with any other nodes
N3: you may get A or nothing, depending on whether the request gets handled by N1 or N2
```

If you read with CL=QUORUM:

```
N1: you get A, and N2 gets updated due to repair on read
N2: you get A, because it checks against N1 and repairs
N3: you get A, because both N1 and N2 will reliably return it
```

You can easily check to see if this is your issue by using QUORUM reads.  If so, the problem will not reappear.

Comment: I tore down the database and re-populated it using a write consistency of ALL. When I run the query with read consistency of ALL I'm still getting inconsistent results. Really at a loss here...

Comment: If you query using `cqlsh` or `cassandra-cli` do you ever get the missing data issue?  Or is this just when running your app?